# spring3 spel if-then-else with bean and place-holder in @value

Tags: java, spring, spring-batch, spring-annotations

i have a problem with Spring SpEL to evaluate if-then-else construct in @Value annotation:

---

### 1. my config.xml file:

```
<context:annotation-config />

<context:property-placeholder location="file://${HOME}/maven.props/${USER}.properties" properties-ref="props" />


<bean id="props" class="java.util.Properties">
    <constructor-arg>
        <props>
            <prop key="interfaceName">createupdateproduct</prop>
            <prop key="destImportFilesDirectoryPath">${batch.job.import.zipDestinationPath}/${interfaceName}/imported</prop>
            <prop key="sourceImportFilesDirectoryPath">${batch.job.import.sourceImportPath}/${interfaceName}/import</prop>
            <prop key="reportDirectoryPath">${batch.job.import.reportPath}/createupdateproduct/report</prop>
        </props>
    </constructor-arg>
</bean>
```

---

### 2. in my bean, i have:

```
@Value("#{jobParameters['destFile']} ?: ${destImportFilesDirectoryPath}")
private String destImportFilesDirectoryPath;
```

---

Question. I would like to switch to the place-holder value, if the bean jobParameters['destFile'] is null. jobParameters is a bean that Spring Batch puts in the context.

The previous code-snippet does not work correctly but both #{jobParameters['destFile']} and ${destImportFilesDirectoryPath} are evaluated correctly singularly :O

I try different solutions, like:

`@Value("#{jobParameters['destFile']} != null  ? #{jobParameters['destFile']} : ${destImportFilesDirectoryPath}")`

OR

`@Value("#{ org.apache.commons.lang.StringUtils.isNotEmpty(#{jobParameters['destFile']}) ? #{jobParameters['destFile']} : ${destImportFilesDirectoryPath} }")`

OR

`@Value("${ #{jobParameters['destFile']} ?: ${destImportFilesDirectoryPath} }")`

but nothing works correctly !

Comment: Don't use a placeholder use SpEL instead. Something like `#{props['destImportFilesDirectoryPath']}` should do the trick.

Comment: can you explain me the complete expression ?

Answer (score 1):

The

```
@Value("#{jobParameters['destFile'] ?: props['destImportFilesDirectoryPath']}")
```

solution does not work: if ("#{jobParameters['destFile']} is valorized, its value is assigned, otherwise it assign null value in the string property.

I have tried also following solution, but without success:

```
 @Value("file:#{jobParameters['destFile'] ?: T((java.util.Properties)props).getProperty('destImportFilesDirectoryPath')}")
```

To differentiate the batch jobs, i use other parameters, like user, interoperability interface name etc.

Comment: Please comment my answer, don't open a new one :)

Answer (score 0):

If you want to use spEL try

```
@Value("#{jobParameters['destFile'] ?: props['destImportFilesDirectoryPath']}")
```

but, IMO, best option is to fill `'destFile'` with the right value before start the job itself.

Also I have a (maybe stupid) question:
job parameters are used to identify in unique manner a job; are you sure you want to store `'null'` as jobparameter value and change it during runtime? what happens if you run job the second time?

Comment: Your question is comprehensible question, but i have others parameters that make me able to  
differentiate my restartable job, like user and the interoperability interface name. :) thank you to answer me, i try your solution

Comment: `@Value("#{'jobParameters[destFile]' ?: '${destImportFilesDirectoryPath:}'}")`

Comment: The 

    @Value("#{jobParameters['destFile'] ?: props['destImportFilesDirectoryPath']}") 

solution does not work: if ("#{jobParameters['destFile']} is valorized, its value is assigned, otherwise it assign null value in the string property.                                                      i'll try @Value("#{'jobParameters[destFile]' ?: '${destImportFilesDirectoryPath:}'}") :)

Comment: @Value("#{'jobParameters[destFile]' ?: '${destImportFilesDirectoryPath:}'}")                                not work again, it assign: "[class path resource [jobParameters[destFile]]]" value.